# What is the best way to include links and code in a textbox for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Is there a way to include links and formatted code without a 3rd party control? Is there a good third party control to use if not?

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head, [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and [FreeTextBox](http://freetextbox.com/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [HTMLEditor](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx) included in the lateset version of the AJAX Control Toolkit, or [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/).